# How do you trace microservices with the AWS X-Ray SDK for Go?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, trace, aws-xray

My goal is to see in Xray service Lens A -> B -> A, but that's not the case:

[image: Missing link to B]

I've instrumented my handlers with `xray.Handler` and I'm fetching the B endpoint with xray context too like so `ctxhttp.Get(r.Context(), xray.Client(nil), endpoint)`, still the traces do not seem to align!

A ID Root=1-6117a4c9-05351c6d72b1ece16f9acd25;Parent=40ef9f0e18b68969;Sampled=1
B ID Root=1-6117a4ca-42a190ac2cf7d6dd4fe06212;Parent=5d8bf2d95170b02c;Sampled=1

I placed the minimal reproducible code upon https://github.com/kaihendry/x-amzn-trace-id

What am I missing please?

Comment: I've tracked down the issue, x-amzn-trace-id is getting stripped somehow.